# I am beginner so I am doubtfull about my solutions. Can anyone check my solution, please?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Suppose that all terms of the sequence $(c_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ are positive and that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n$ diverges. Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence with limit $t$. (may be $±∞$).
Define $ σ_n=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_k a_k}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_k}$ Show that $\lim_{n→∞}σ_n = t$.

My solution: Let $\varepsilon>0$ be choosen then there is a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ then for all $n\geqslant N$, $|a_n-t|<\varepsilon$

\begin{align}\left|\frac{c_1a_1+\cdots+c_na_n}{c_1+\cdots+c_n}-t\right|&=
\frac{1}{c_1+\cdots+c_n}|c_1a_1+\cdots+c_na_n-(c_1+\cdots+c_n)t|\\&=\frac{1}{c_1+\cdots+c_n}|c_1a_1+\cdots+c_na_n-c_1t-\cdots-c_nt|\\&=\frac{1}{c_1+\cdots+c_n}|c1(a1-t)+\cdots+c_N(a_N-t)+\cdots+c_n(a_n-t)|\\&<\frac{1}{c_1+\cdots+c_n}|c_1(a_1-t)+\cdots+c_N \varepsilon +\cdots+c_n \varepsilon|\\&=\frac{1}{c_1+\cdots+c_n}|c_1(a_1-t)+\cdots+\varepsilon(c_N+...+c_n)|\\&<\frac{1}{c_1+\cdots+c_n}|c_1(a_1-t)+\cdots+c_{N-1}(a_{N-1}-t)|+\\&\quad+\frac{1}{c_1+\cdots+c_n}|\varepsilon (c_N+\cdots+c_n)|\\&<\frac{1}{c_1+\cdots+c_n}|c_1(a_1-t)+\cdots+c_{N-1}(a_{N-1}-t)|+\\&\quad+\frac{1}{c_N+\cdots+c_n}|\varepsilon(c_N+\cdots+c_n)|\\&=\frac{1}{c_1+\cdots+c_n}|c_1(a_1-t)+...+c_{N-1}(a_{N-1}-t)|+\varepsilon\end{align}

So if $n\to\infty$ then $\left|\frac{c_1a_1+\cdots+c_na_n}{c_1+\cdots+c_n}-t\right|<\varepsilon$

Comment: The inequality $|c1(a1-t)+\cdots+c_N(a_N-t)+\cdots+c_n(a_n-t)| <|c_1(a_1-t)+\cdots+c_N \varepsilon +\cdots+c_n \varepsilon|$ does not hold. But you can use that $|c1(a1-t)+\cdots+c_N(a_N-t)+\cdots+c_n(a_n-t)| \le |c1(a1-t)|+\cdots+|c_N(a_N-t)|+\cdots+|c_n(a_n-t)| <|c_1(a_1-t)|+\cdots+c_N \varepsilon +\cdots+c_n \varepsilon|$

Comment: could you explain I couldnt understand why it does not hold?

Comment: Suppose that $n=N=2.$ Then $c_1(a_1-t)+c_2(a_2-t)<c_1(a_1-t)+c_2\epsilon$ but we can't say that $|c_1(a_1-t)+c_2(a_2-t)|<|c_1(a_1-t)+c_2\epsilon|.$